# Jcrop plugin isn't working with resize function

Tags: php, jquery, html, resize, jcrop

My Jcrop plugin isn't working properly.

I can select an area to crop, but there are no little resize squares at the edges. I don't know if this is a specific function or a default setting.

This is what I mean. My crop area looks like this now:

[image: my picture]

My crop background is red and the selected area has the original color, but the strange thing is that there are no resize squares like in this picture:

[image: good picture]

My code looks like this:

The head:

```
<head>
    <title>Het Vergeet-mij-nietje</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/showfunctie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/css/demos.css" type="text/css" />

    <script language="Javascript">
        jQuery(function($){

          var jcrop_api;

          $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
            bgColor: 'red'
          },function(){
            jcrop_api = this;
          });

          $('#animbutton').click(function(e){
            jcrop_api.animateTo([ 120,120,80,80 ]);
            return false;
          });

          $('#delselect').click(function(e){
            jcrop_api.release();
            return false;
          });

        });
        </script>
</head>
```

My image code:

```
 <div id="content1">
 <?php 
     $target = "uploads/"; 
     $target = $_POST["imagesource"];        
     $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']) ; 
     $ok=1; 
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
     {
     echo "De afbeelding *". basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']). "* is geupload naar de map 'uploads'";
     } 
     else {
     echo "Sorry, er is een probleem met het uploaden van de afbeelding.";
     }
 ?> 
 <br /> <br />

 <img id="cropbox" src="<?php echo $target ?>" width="400px" />

 <br /> <br />
</div>
```

I hope someone knows what's the problem :)

Comment: link to the page with issue will help

Comment: i can't get the fiddle to work properly. http://jsfiddle.net/94JSs/1/

Comment: Solved it already, see comment below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=styling) JCrop styling example? maybe it's a CSS problem?

Do you have a live example of your code?

Comment: i made a very stupid fault. for some reason my jquery.jcrop.css file did not work. but now it does by calling it again in the head tag. thanks for your answer, without this answer i had no idea what te problem was +1 :)